# Facebook Share "swallowing" parameters or disappearing

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm having troubles trying to share a page with parameters on Facebook. This is the code I'm using:

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
    var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
    var dualScreenTop  = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
    var width  = window.innerWidth  ? window.innerWidth  : document.documentElement.clientWidth  ? document.documentElement.clientWidth  : screen.width ;
    var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;
    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft ;
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop  ;
    var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
}
```

and the URL is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2127.0.0.1%3A50846%2FIndex.html%3Faction%3DDO1%26param%3D4cf13a1311fe40afa401b25ef7fa0379f1f7c1930a04f8755d678474d0c30e0c
```

where there are in fact two parameters:

1. action=DO1, and
2. param=4cf13a1311fe40afa401b25ef7fa0379f1f7c1930a04f8755d678474d0c30e0c

Initially, I didn't encode the shared URL (meaning, was using `=`,`/`, `&` characters) and the share worked but the parameters were missing. Now that I'm entering an encoded URL, the Facebook's window pops but immediately disappears.

Could anyone tell me how can I manage to share a URL with parameters **without** the need of switching to the feed share mechanism?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you want to share a localhost url? that does not make any sense...

Comment: I'm currently working in a test environment. The only thing I want to see right now is that the link embedded into the Facebook's share post is correct. As soon as it works as needed, the URL will be corrected to the real value.

Comment: try with a public url, not with localhost. you can't test it like that.

Comment: OK. Will do and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using the method **`encodeURIComponent`**, so my function is now:

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
    var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
    var dualScreenTop  = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
    var width  = window.innerWidth  ? window.innerWidth  : document.documentElement.clientWidth  ? document.documentElement.clientWidth  : screen.width ;
    var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;
    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft ;
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop  ;
    var newWindow = window.open(encodeURIComponent(url), title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
};
```

and it works like a charm!!